# How to specify new Uri instance with already escaped path segment?

Tags: .net, .net-core, escaping, uri

I would need to construct an instance of [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-2.2) class where one of the path parts must have the slash character '/' inside.
For example I would need to send to the web server the following URL where the DDDD/2019 should not be intepreted as a path part:

```
http://localhost/some/path/DDDD/2019
```

In order to have this correctly interpreted by the server I need to escape the DDDD/2019:

```
http://localhost/some/path/DDDD%2F2019
```

If I give (escaped) string to the Uri class constructor it will additionally escape the Uri. This means that my server will receive `DDDD%2F2019` as a parameter and not `DDDD/2019`.

I can solve this by using the Uri constructor which has 'dontEscape' parameter where I set this parameter to 'true'. The problem is that the .NET (full 4.8 / core 2.2) this parameter is obsolete and I would prefer not to use obsolete methods.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is actually OK. The url is not encoded twice. The problem is in the .NET Core Kestrel which is not decoding the parameter correctly:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4599